# Can I implement FNA without facebook permission?

Tags: cache

I want to implement a facebook cache server for my ISP. But I couldn't find any resources about implementing an FNA server without facebook permission.
I work in a small ISP that does not meet facebook requirements.
Is there any way to cache static content of Facebook, without Facebook's requirement for an FNA node?

Comment: I searched many time but i did not find the correct ans. My point of view its is not possible to implement FNA without Facebook permission.Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hamza khan, I am reaching to the same thing too.

Answer (score -2):

You can find hardware lists and installation instructions at https://kupdf.net/download/fna-installation-and-operation-guide-v804_597ff4a4dc0d6055102bb17e_pdf

Comment: This requires Facebook's cooperation. OP wants to do it without that.

Comment: I have already read that book and as @ceejayoz said that requires Facebook cooperation. Thanks for your reply but always read the question carefully first.